# How to simulate a star network in NS2 and drop packets given certain conditions?

Tags: networking, ns2

I'm new to ns2 and I have got it installed and going in Ubuntu. However, I need to create a 5-node star network in ns2 and send packets from one node to another via the central hub node. The hub node will inspect packets being passed and if the packet contains '111', the packet will be dropped.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Create a simulator object
set ns [new Simulator]

#Open the nam trace file
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

#Define a 'finish' procedure
proc finish {} {
    global ns nf
    $ns flush-trace
    #Close the trace file
    close $nf
    #Executenam on the trace file
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit0
}


#Create four nodes
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]


#Change the shape of center node in a star topology
$n0 shape square

#Create links between the nodes
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n5 1Mb 10ms DropTail


#Create a TCP agent and attach it to node n0
set tcp0 [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp0 set class_ 1
$ns attach-agent $n1 $tcp0
#Create a TCP Sink agent (a traffic sink) for TCP and attach it to node n3
set sink0 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n3 $sink0
#Connect the traffic sources with the traffic sink
$ns connect $tcp0 $sink0


# Create a CBR traffic source and attach it to tcp0
set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set interval_ 0.01
$cbr0 attach-agent $tcp0

#Schedule events for the CBR agents
$ns at 0.5 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.5 "$cbr0 stop"


#Call the finish procedure after 5 seconds of simulation time
$ns at 5.0 "finish"

#Run the simulation
$ns run
```

How do I add the logic for testing the contents of a packet being passed and dropping it if '111' is observed in the data field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in protocol's codes, and as we know the protocols have been written with c++ language in NS2.
If you intend to do this i will help you, just leave a comment.